# sugarcrm globalsearch custom field

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to  implement the Global search for the Leads for the Primary address field ,i

followed the folllowing steps following [this link](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/04/29/howto-add-custom-fields-into-the-global-search/).

once that has been done i have done quick repair and rebuild but im not able to get the 
result .Any more thing to be done?

created a new file named customGlobalSearchFields.php in  `/custom/Extension/modules/Leads/ext/Vardefs/`

and added the code below:

```
$dictionary['Leads']['fields']['primary_address_street']['unified_search'] = true;
```

Also added `custom\modules\Leads\metadata\SearchFields.php`

```
'primary_address_street' => 
  array (
    'query_type' => 'default',
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled the Leads module for Global Search, right?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code..

> custom\modules\Leads\metadata\SearchFields.php

```
'primary_address_street' => 
  array (
    'query_type' => 'default',
    'force_unifiedsearch'=>true
  ),
```

Banti Gehlot